# get the jquery index of "td" element

Tags: jquery

I have markup

```
 <table>
    <tr id="1">
        <td colspan="4">
            <p class="que">
                1. Who are you?</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ans">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />Student
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="true" />Developer
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />Other
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>​​​
```

Here I want to get the index of the particular td which has its checkbox checked. For example here it should be 1. But I m getting 0 eachtime which seems like the index of the row.
Here is the jquery code I have used.

```
   var answers = $('table tr.ans');
 $.each(answers, function () {
  var answer = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").index(); 
    alert(answer);                   
  });​
```

and here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/parush/Xj8aK/)
How do I get the index of the particular td?
Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it with

```
$("table tr.ans input[type='checkbox']:checked").parent().index();
```

You simply need to navigate from the checkbox back up to the `<td>`, at which point stright calling `.index` does the trick:

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is
>   an integer indicating the position of the first element within the
>   jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/eLSWp/)**.

Since you are doing this inside a loop, a more proper fit would be

```
var answer = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").parent().index();
```

Comment: You can't combine the selectors. This would only work if there were one answer section.

Answer (score 2):

Change the line to this:

```
var answer = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").parent().index();
```

This will give you the index of the `td` that is the parent of the input you have selected in your jquery selector.