# i want TD index from table using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this table. What I want is when there is a click on edit button than it will show me its TD index on page load as alert. Thanks in advance I hope someone help me...

How to get html table td cell index by javascript?

```
        <tbody>
            <tr class="row" >
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td class="lalign" >0
                </td>

                <td >Route 3
                </td>

                <td >3
                </td>
                <td id="long">77.22496
                </td>

                <td  id="lat">30.242607
                </td>

                <td >null
                </td>
                <td >3
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Edit" onclick=""/>
                    <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)"/>

                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613873/get-the-jquery-index-of-td-element

Answer (score 2):

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/muralim/dXRVs/2/)

```
   <td>
          <input type="button" value="Edit" onclick=""/>
           <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/>
   </td>
```

Then

```
function deleteRow(obj){

var index= $(obj).closest("td").index();

}
```

Comment: @AshishSrivastava, check the fiddle demo. It returns 8

Comment: it always give 8 for every row

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ashishsrivastava22/GQ4xY/) See It

Answer (score 1):

```
$(SELECTOR).closest("td").index();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
     <tbody>
            <tr class="row" >
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td class="lalign" >0
                </td>

                <td >Route 3
                </td>

                <td >3
                </td>
                <td id="long">77.22496
                </td>

                <td  id="lat">30.242607
                </td>

                <td >null
                </td>
                <td >3
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Edit" onclick=""/>
                    <input type="button" class="deleteBtn" value="Delete"/>

                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

jQuery>

```
$(".deleteBtn").click( function(){

var index= $(this).closest("td").index();
alert(index);
});
```

[FIddLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TfcVt/)

**Updated:**

If you want the current cell number relative to the parent row:

```
var indextd= $(this).closest("td").index()+1;
alert(indextd);
```

If you want the current cell number relative to the containing table:

```
var indextd= $(this).closest("td").index()+1;
var indextr= $(this).closest("tr").index()+1;
    
alert(indextd*indextr);
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TfcVt/1/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishsrivastava22/GQ4xY/  See this 
it always give me 8

Comment: It will give 8 because it always check the index of the current td of its parent tr

Comment: do you want cell index of the containing table.?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `id` `edit` to edit button `<input id="edit" type="button" value="Edit" onclick=""/>`  and then you can do something like this:

Updated HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="row" >
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td class="lalign" >0
            </td>

            <td >Route 3
            </td>

            <td >3
            </td>
            <td id="long">77.22496
            </td>

            <td  id="lat">30.242607
            </td>

            <td >null
            </td>
            <td >3
            </td>

            <td>
                <input id="edit" type="button" value="Edit" onclick=""/>
                <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)"/>

            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#edit').click(function(){
       console.log($(this).parent("td").index()); 
    });
});
```

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/fYQ8y/)**